# PowerMock StackOveflowError on ArrayListMultimap

Tags: java, mocking, guava, easymock, powermock

**EDIT:** This is now filed as an issue with Powermock here: http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=449&thanks=449&ts=1371519268

I was testing some code using EasyMock that calls a method that returns an ArrayListMultimap and I didn't want to go to the trouble of constructing a collection object full of mocks, so I decided to simply mock the ArrayListMultimap and make it return whatever mocks I wanted in standard mock object fasion. ArrayListMultimap turns out to be final, so I threw some PowerMock pixy dust on it. However when I ran my test I got:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.copy(Method.java:143)
    at java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.copyMethod(ReflectAccess.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.copyMethod(ReflectionFactory.java:282)
    at java.lang.Class.copyMethods(Class.java:2757)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1793)
    at org.easymock.internal.BridgeMethodResolver.getAllDeclaredMethods(BridgeMethodResolver.java:434)
    at org.easymock.internal.BridgeMethodResolver.findBridgedMethod(BridgeMethodResolver.java:78)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:87)
    at com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2dd82dd1.equals(<generated>)
    at org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocation.matches(ExpectedInvocation.java:85)
    at org.easymock.internal.UnorderedBehavior.addActual(UnorderedBehavior.java:57)
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksBehavior.addActual(MocksBehavior.java:87)
    at org.easymock.internal.ReplayState.invokeInner(ReplayState.java:58)
    at org.easymock.internal.ReplayState.invoke(ReplayState.java:46)
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:40)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:94)
    at com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2dd82dd1.equals(<generated>)
    at org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocation.matches(ExpectedInvocation.java:85)
    at org.easymock.internal.UnorderedBehavior.addActual(UnorderedBehavior.java:57)
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksBehavior.addActual(MocksBehavior.java:87)
    at org.easymock.internal.ReplayState.invokeInner(ReplayState.java:58)
    at org.easymock.internal.ReplayState.invoke(ReplayState.java:46)
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:40)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:94)
    at com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2dd82dd1.equals(<generated>)
    at org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocation.matches(ExpectedInvocation.java:85)
    at org.easymock.internal.UnorderedBehavior.addActual(UnorderedBehavior.java:57)
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksBehavior.addActual(MocksBehavior.java:87)
    at org.easymock.internal.ReplayState.invokeInner(ReplayState.java:58)
    at org.easymock.internal.ReplayState.invoke(ReplayState.java:46)
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:40)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:94)
    at com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2dd82dd1.equals(<generated>)
    at org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocation.matches(ExpectedInvocation.java:85)
    at org.easymock.internal.UnorderedBehavior.addActual(UnorderedBehavior.java:57)
    at org.easymock.internal.MocksBehavior.addActual(MocksBehavior.java:87)
    at org.easymock.internal.ReplayState.invokeInner(ReplayState.java:58)
    at org.easymock.internal.ReplayState.invoke(ReplayState.java:46)
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:40)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:94)
    at com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2dd82dd1.equals(<generated>)
    at org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocation.matches(ExpectedInvocation.java:85)
    at org.easymock.internal.UnorderedBehavior.addActual(UnorderedBehavior.java:57)
```

Eventually I distilled the problem down to this example:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ArrayListMultimap.class)
public class PurePowermockTest {

  @Test
  public void testPowerMockVsGuava() {
    ArrayListMultimap map = PowerMock.createMock(ArrayListMultimap.class);
    expect(map.put("foo", "bar")).andReturn(true);
    PowerMock.replay(map);
    map.put("foo", "bar");  // SOError!
  }
}
```

The above example of course doesn't test anything, the map.put() call would normally be inside some method I am testing. This code is just to demonstrate the problem as concisely as possible. I'm also aware that I can just build the ArrayListMultiMap and return it, but setting that aside, mocking the map should work too. I'm pretty certain this is a bug in powermock, but my question is this:

Am I using PowerMock correctly? Should this work, or is there something I've missed about PowerMock's capabilities or proper usage? I'm using the EasyMock.expect method, but I don't see an equivalent on PowerMock, so I assume this is ok...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug in PowerMock to me (or javassist which is used to bytecode manipulation). Since I'm using PowerMock with Mockito (i.e. PowerMockito) I've checked if it's reproducible with Mockito - and it is. Given the test:

```
@PrepareForTest(ArrayListMultimap.class)
public class PowerMockitoTest {

  @Rule // used instead @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) in newer version of JUnit
  public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

  @Test
  public void testPowerMockitoVsGuava() {
    final ArrayListMultimap<String, String> mock =
        PowerMockito.mock(ArrayListMultimap.class);
    PowerMockito.when(mock.put("foo", "bar")).thenReturn(true);
    Assert.assertTrue(mock.put("foo", "bar")); // SOError!
  }

}
```

it still produces SO and points to equals in proxied ArrayListMultimap's class (`at com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2dd82dd1.equals(<generated>)` in stacktrace).

This particular bug may be related to recurring [issue 88](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=88) - it mentions SO errors when equals is final (but in ArrayListMultimap it isn't...) or uses getClass() in it (it doesn't, uses instanceof on the other hand) or calls another method from equals (it might be a case here, since `asMap()` is called inside `AbstractMultimap#equals`). On the other hand I checked `LinkedListMultimap` which works fine with PowerMock, so it could be something with `ArrayListMultimap` type hierarchy (extends `AbstractMultimap` -> `AbstractMapBasedMultimap` -> `AbstractListMultimap` while `LinkedListMultimap` doesn't).

Unfortunately I don't know PowerMock internals and haven't found anything concrete, so you should contact PowerMock devs, probably via [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/powermock).

---

Back to your problem - if you can change your method to return `ListMultimap`, then you're good - you should operate on interface and not on concrete implementation anyway (and you don't even have to use PowerMock). `LinkedListMultimap` is also an option here.

Comment: That's good confirmation that it's powermock. I filed this as an issue here: http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=449&thanks=449&ts=1371519268